# The error "Non-generic method" IParentNode.QuerySelector (string) "cannot be used with type arguments. "

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I try to log in to the site using the AngleSharp library.
I use code for this.

```
class Program
{
    const string sourceToSite = "https://mail.ru/";
    const string sourceToTarget = "https://e.mail.ru/messages/inbox/";

    static async void QueryToOrders()
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies();
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        await context.OpenAsync(sourceToSite);
        var check = context.Active.QuerySelector<IHtmlFormElement>("form#Auth").SubmitAsync(new { Login = EMAIL + "@mail.ru", Password = PASSWORD }).Result;
        var msgs = await context.OpenAsync(sourceToTarget);
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> "The error "Non-generic method" IParentNode.QuerySelector (string) "cannot be used with type arguments."

Question
How to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the form of `QuerySelector` that takes a generic argument is an extension method. You need to add a `using` for the namespace it lives in:

```
using AngleSharp.Extensions;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the 0.11 version there is no more `AngleSharp.Extensions` you need:

```
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Dom;
using AngleSharp.Html.Dom;
```

See sample [here](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/master/src/AngleSharp.Core.Tests/Examples/Forms.cs)